# Retrieve JSON data at server side

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, dojo, request

I've a Java EE servlet to which I'm submitting some information in JSON format. Below is the JS code that I'm using to submit the information.

```
   var params = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"};

            var xhrArgs = {
                url: "http://localhost:8080/servlet/testapp",
                postData: dojo.toJson(params),
                handleAs: "json",
                load: function(data) {
                    //Handle load 
                },
                error: function(error) {
    //handle error
                }
            };

            var deferred = dojo.rawXhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

Now how do I retrieve the post data at the server end? When i try
`request.getParameter("params")`, I should get the JSON data. 
Could you please let me know how I can implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should be using

```
content:{"params":dojo.toJson(params)}
```

to retrieve the information the server side.